# Using Apache Kafka with prometheus

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus

[request timming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaSQQ.jpg)Currently i am using only prometheus but i want to use kafka with prometheus to optimize my request time would kafka can help me to improve my response time ?

Currently when hitting my prometheus api to get metrics it's respone time is from 350ms - 700ms i want decrease that time to less than 200ms

So just need recommendation would using kakfa with prometheus can help me in this ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. What response time? How does kafka correlate with prometheus? You can see metrics in prometheus. Kafka is messaging system. Try to write more meaningful description

Comment: Yes prometheus is giving me metrics but when ever it take little time to respone so i just want to know that if i send prometheus metrics to kafka and then consume those metrics from kafka.
Would this optimize  my request time ?

I have attached my respone time image i want to optimize the respone time if kafka would not help me to do so can recommend any other way ?

Comment: I don't see how adding an extra service would improve the speed of anything

Answer (score 0):

I think you might mixing up a bit.

Prometheus does contains any Kafka messaging middleware to ingest metrics ( actually prometheus is more like scraping metrics pages) or to expose metrics.

Here a document talking about Prometheus data export, that can maybe help tuning your queries :
https://medium.com/@valyala/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639

Comment: Yes i know prometheus is used for monitoring and kafka is a pub-sub application.But respone time for prometheus is very high i was just thinking that would it be possible if i send prometheus metric using kafka could decrease the request timing ?